# Why does close() only work in one method and not the other?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void test();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

void MainWindow::test()
{
    close(); // Line 1
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    close(); // Line 2
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.test();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If I comment out the close() in line 2, the close() in line 1 closes the window and leaves the application running.

If I comment out the close() in line 1, the close() in line 2 closes the window and ends the application.

Why is there this difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for this is that `w.test()` call is called before event loop has been started (`a.exec()`), so it will not cause any other event to happen which could be related to `close()` operation of `QMainWindow`.

In the second approach, your `close()` function will be called after event loop has been  started, better said, within your event loop (when you click the button, you will be dispatched to `on_pushButton_clicked()` method, and `close()` will inform your application that it needs to be ended.

In order to run `test()` function in event loop, use single-shot timer:

```
//Qt 4 - in Qt 5, you can work this out without helper slot:

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow{
    //...   
    void test();
    //...
public slots:
    void testHelper(){ test(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &w, SLOT(testHelper()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Edit**

It seems that Qt5's new `connect` syntax will not help you here to avoid additional slot [[1]](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26406)

> Qt5 having a new connection syntax which allows for the use of lambdas and QtConcurrent already beeing capable of using lambdas QTimer or more specifically QTimer::singleShot() is lacking both.
>   It would be convenient (and consistent) to have function pointer syntax and lambda support for QTimer::singleShot() as well.

**Edit 2**

To be more precise, when you call `QMainWindow::close()`, `QMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)` event is raised, and normally it should be processed in the current event loop. Since there is no event loop in the point of calling `close`, this event is not caught up and nothing will cause application to exit.

Comment: Thank you for explaining too instead of just giving the solution.